# Why reference to vector in lambda in overloaded ostream operator causes an error?

Tags: c++

In my matrix implementation I have used vector of vectors as a private member. I have overloaded `ostream` operator, so I can print all values from my matrix. In code below I am using first `for_each` to iterate over "rows" of my matrix. In lambda I am specyfing an argument (matrix "column") being a reference to vector, at the end of this line:

```
std::for_each(p_matrix.m_vector_of_vectors.begin(), p_matrix.m_vector_of_vectors.end(), [& p_out] (std::vector<int> & el)
```

This causes an error. Here is full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Matrix{
  public:
    Matrix()
    {
       m_vector_of_vectors = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    }
    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & p_out, const Matrix & p_matrix)
    {
        std::for_each(p_matrix.m_vector_of_vectors.begin(), p_matrix.m_vector_of_vectors.end(), [& p_out] (std::vector<int> & el)
        {
            std::for_each(el.begin(), el.end(), [& p_out] (int & el2)
            {
                p_out << el2 << " "; 
            });
            p_out << std::endl;
        });
        return p_out;
    }
  private:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> m_vector_of_vectors;
};

int main()
{
    Matrix l_matrix;
    std::cout << l_matrix;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is full error print:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/algorithm:62:0,
                 from main.cpp:11:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:

In instantiation of ‘_Funct std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::vector<int>*, std::vector<std::vector<int> > >; _Funct = operator<<(std::ostream&, Matrix)::<lambda(std::vector<int>&)>]’:
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.cpp',29)">main.cpp:29:10</span>:   required from here

/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:3767:5: error: no match for call to ‘(operator<<(std::ostream&, Matrix)::&)>) (const std::vector&)’
 __f(*__first);

main.cpp:22:129: note: candidate: operator<<(std::ostream&, Matrix)::&)> 
         std::for_each(p_matrix.m_vector_of_vectors.begin(), p_matrix.m_vector_of_vectors.end(), [& p_out] (std::vector<int> & el)
```

**Without a reference everything works fine:**

```
std::for_each(p_matrix.m_vector_of_vectors.begin(), p_matrix.m_vector_of_vectors.end(), [& p_out] (std::vector<int> el)
```

Can someone explain why this single reference is crucial? In second (inner) lambda code works with and without reference. The same is with p_matrix parameter in overloaded operator. I have tried looping over vector of vectors being normal variable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> a = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    std::for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), [] (std::vector<int> & el)
    {
       std::for_each(el.begin(), el.end(), [] (int & el2)
       {
          std::cout << el2; 
       });
    });

    return 0;
}
```

and this works fine, so I am assuming that this error has something to do with overloaded operator. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & p_out, const Matrix & p_matrix)
```

`p_matrix` is `const`.  That means `p_matrix.m_vector_of_vectors` is `const` which means `p_matrix.m_vector_of_vectors.begin()` returns a `const_iterator` which means the element passed to the lambda is `const`.  Since your lambda takes a non const reference that it incompatible.  It would strip away the `const` of the element and that isn't allowed.  Change the lambdas to take const reference like

```
friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & p_out, const Matrix & p_matrix)
{
    std::for_each(p_matrix.m_vector_of_vectors.begin(), p_matrix.m_vector_of_vectors.end(), [& p_out] (std::vector<int> const & el) // <- const here
    {
        std::for_each(el.begin(), el.end(), [& p_out] (int const & el2) //<- const here
        {
            p_out << el2 << " "; 
        });
        p_out << std::endl;
    });
    return p_out;
}
```

and the code will compile.  You don't need this in your second example because `a` isn't `const` so its iterator isn't `const` meaning the element it passes to the lambda isn't `const`.

I'd also like to point out that ranged based for loop would make the code a lot more condensed.  You can change your `operator <<` to

```
friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & p_out, const Matrix & p_matrix)
{
    for (auto const& row : p_matrix.m_vector_of_vectors)
    {
        for (auto const& e : row)
            p_out << e << " ";
        p_out << "\n";
    }
    return p_out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was asking about!

Answer (score 3):

You take `Matrix` by const-ref, (this is correct), therefore, you have to either take the vector by const-ref as well (or by value, which involves a copy):

```
std::for_each(
  p_matrix.m_vector_of_vectors.begin(),
  p_matrix.m_vector_of_vectors.end(),
  [& p_out] (***const*** std::vector<int> & el)
...
```

(Your second example works because `a` is non-const, therefore the lambda can take a non-const-ref)

Comment: Ok, I see now, that when I use const-ref to Matrix in operator I need also cons-ref in my lambda. Thanks!